# Are there any IR apis available for Android?

Tags: android

I recently got a Galaxy Tab 2, which includes a remote control., I tried to google some api availability, but couldn't find anything. Is there anyway to use IR controls on a custom app, or is it locked down by Samsung?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

REALLY late answer but to those who find this question...

I was looking for a Samsung Infrared API as well. I found only [this Samsung Developers forum response](http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=GeneralB&messageId=169734) (dated Sept. 6, 2012) to a similar query where a Samsung representative is indicating that Samsung isn't providing an IR API to the public.

Answer (score 0):

We can control the ir blaster using custom app..its not locked...
u can try this code..

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void click(View v) {

        final ConsumerIrManager irManager = (ConsumerIrManager) getSystemService(CONSUMER_IR_SERVICE);
        Log.i("PowerButton", "Button Clicked.");

        if (irManager.hasIrEmitter()) {
            Log.i("PowerButton", "Has IR Emitter.");

            ConsumerIrManager.CarrierFrequencyRange[] freqRange = irManager.getCarrierFrequencies();

            Log.i("PowerButton", "Min Frequency: " + freqRange[0].getMinFrequency());
            Log.i("PowerButton", "Max Frequency: " + freqRange[0].getMaxFrequency());

            int[] pattern = {/* Insert pattern here */};
            int frequency = 10000;

            irManager.transmit(frequency, pattern);
        } else {
            Log.i("PowerButton", "Does not have an IR Emitter.");
        }




    }
```